# Typescript React - IntrinsicAttributes Error when passing props

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I never had this error before. When I want to pass a props to my SearchItem component I get this error message:

> Type '{ item: HotelModel; key: string; }' is not assignable to type
> 'IntrinsicAttributes'.   Property 'item' does not exist on type
> 'IntrinsicAttributes'.

HotelModel is an interface with different attributes: {_id: string, name: string, rating: number. ...}

Here is the part of the code:

```
function List(): JSX.Element {
 
  const { data, loading, error } = useFetch(`hotel?city=${destination}`);

  return (
    <div>
          <div className="listResult">
            {loading ? (
              'Loading'
            ) : (
              <>
                {data.map((item: HotelModel) => {
                  return <SearchItem item={item} key={item._id} />;
                })}
              </>
            )}
          </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I'm new to Typescript, is there a best practice when it comes to passing props while iterating over an array? Thank you.

Comment: Your `SearchItem` component is not expecting any prop with name `item`. How did you declare your component? You should give it a function signature like so: `const SearchItem: FC<{ item: HotelModel }>() => { // your component code ... }`

Comment: My SearchItem component is written as such: 
function SearchItem(item: HotelModel): JSX.Element {// my code...}
So shouldn't it already be expecting an object like HotelModel?

Comment: No, you are declaring it as a function taking a parameter, which is conceptually (in TS at least) much different from a functional component with parameters.

Comment: Thank you for your help @nbokmans it works now. Will read the documentation some more.